# I installed MongoDB, but It isn't run

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, server

I installed mongoDB on `E:\MongoDB` path in windows 10.
And I set up MongoDB's environment variables and created the `C:\data\db` directory.

Then I executed it using `Mongod` command.

However, it is still in the following state.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Well, it seems to be ready to accept connections. What is the problem?

Comment: Is it already running well?

Comment: *waiting for connections on Port 27017* ... Everything is awesome?